# How to send ctrl + ` in powershell

Tags: powershell, winforms, sendkeys

I want to send the keystrokes <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (not <kbd>~</kbd>) using powershell, but can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried the following, but no good.

```powershell
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{`}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{\`}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^`')
```

Answer (score 2):

In a double-quoted string the backroom is used as an escape character. Either double it out use a single-quoted string. The backslash doesn't do anything useful there, as PowerShell doesn't use backslashes for escaping except in regexes.